# Jquery addclass not working in any browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to addclass to the element using jquery. I used recommended syntax but the jquery still not work. The thing i want to is that when user clicks signup, he will see signup form otherwise login. Also, i have set signup form to hidden using css. Now i am trying to addclass .active to the element but i got stuck. My html looks like

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $(".signup_form").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.signup_form {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.active {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form_inner">
  <ul class="user_form_nav">
    <li class="login_form" name="login">
      <a href="#loginform">Login</a>
    </li>
    <li class="signup_form" id="signup" name="signup">
      <a href="#signupform">SignUp</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
   </div>
```

any suggestion.

Comment: You're attaching the click event to `signup_form`, which is hidden in CSS. Essentially, you're attaching a click event to an invisible element. I'm not exactly clear on what's expected?

Comment: How is the user supposed to click the `signup` button if it's invisible?

Comment: There is no element in your example with a class of `user_form_signup`. However, if you add this element (and put quotes around the selector in your JavaScript), it works just as you want it to...

Comment: So as I said above, now that you've edited your question, the code works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can toggle login form and sign up form with `.show()` and `.hide()`;

I have added a snippet, hope this is what you are trying to achieve. cheers..:D

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $(".signup_form").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#sign-up-form').show();
    $('#login-form').hide()
  });
  $('#login').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#sign-up-form').hide();
    $('#login-form').show()
  })
});
```

```css
.active {
  display: block;
}
.sign-up{
  display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form_inner">
  <ul class="user_form_nav">
    <li class="login_form" id="login" name="login">
      <a href="#loginform">Login</a>
    </li>
    <li class="signup_form" id="signup" name="signup">
      <a href="#signupform">SignUp</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  <div id="login-form">
    <h2>Login Form</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="sign-up" id="sign-up-form">
    <h2> Sign Up Form</h2>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
$signUpAnchor = $(".user_form_signup")
$signUpAnchor.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $signUpAnchor.addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Try that, the $this call in your function does most likely point to the scope of the event. So not to your anchor.

The anchor has default on click behaviour so we need to prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot click on elements with `visibility:hidden`, try `opacity` instead:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$(".signup_form").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.signup_form {
    opacity:0;
}

.active {
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="user_form_nav">
    <li class="login_form" name="login" >
      <a href="#loginform">Login</a>  
    </li>
    <li class="signup_form"  id="signup" name="signup" >
        <a href="#signupform">SignUp</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `visibility`, why don't you use `display` instead ? if you do, it should work just fine.

```
.user_form_signup {
     display: none;
}
.active {
     display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Instead if addClass try using ToggleClass.

Option 2: Instead of visibility, try using width and height, giving it both 0. And the active class with width and height to auto or as you prefer

Option 3: Replace addClass to ToggleClass and instead of visibility set display as none for sign-up and for active to block